# PreInit doesn't always seem to apply

Tags: asp.net, preinit

Because of the situation, I have a radiobuttonlist control within the page that's populated within the control

In preinit, I then check and see the sql enrollment count and if it's above a certain number, disable it.  I've been doing this call in the pre-init and most of the time it seems to work fine.  However, we've had a few instances where the control item has not been disabled.

I've tried to read up on the page cycle stages and then I just tried a few things, but it appears that the only place I can really manipulate the controls is during page preinit and page load.

Every time I check, everything is disabled appropriately.  But, sometimes, a user has been able to check and submit an item that should be disabled.  My only thought is that if the database cannot be contacted, it's not disabling the list item?  Or, does anyone else have any ideas?  Should I just bite the bullet and put everything in page load?

Thanks.

Comment: if I understand correctly , you want to disable or enable the controls based on the value you get from the database is it? in that case you can just have your control disabled in the declaration of the control in the aspx , then in the page load you can manipulate them after getting them from the data base

Answer (score 1):

PreInit is not the best choice to change controls properties, because viewstate wasn't loaded yet. If the request is a postback, the properties you set may be overriden when viewstate is load.

For more information about what happens in each stage of page life cicle, check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Sergio, yeah I tried that link, but obviously didn't get it.  I'll just redo and put in page load.  Bummer.

Comment: Sergio, I've tried putting it in the page load, if not page.ispostback  But, now it doesn't retain the individual list item being disabled.  Any tips?

Comment: Let me amend that, my folks want the item to appear, but be disabled and a different color.  If I do that on page load, not page.ispostback, the enabled stays false, but myItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "gray") is lost.  How can I make that stay?

Comment: Attributes property is not saved to viewstate. You have two options, move the property assignment out of "not page.isPostBack" or save the index of diabled itens in viewstate and restore them on postback ([link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So, I could add the keyfields in an array list below and then iterate through the radiobuttonlists on page.ispostback?:
Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me.ViewState.Add("arrayListInViewState", PageArrayList)
End Sub

Comment: Exactly. You can load state on PageLoad, add the logic you need on the array list, and then save it's state on PageRender.